# Change image A & B when hover image C

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs, `A`, `B` & `C`, and each have 3 different backgrounds depending on which of the three div is hovered over.

The idea is to change background of the `divs` as follows:

- On hover of `A`, change `A` background to `a1`, `B` to `b1` and `C` to `c1`
- On hover of `B`, change `A` background to `a2`, `B` to `b2` and `C` to `c2`
- On hover of `C`, change `A` background to `a3`, `B` to `b3` and `C` to `c3`

It seems that when trying to change the background of a `div` that comes before the `:hover` `div` it fails.

#### HTML

```html
<div class="team1"></div>
<div class="team2"></div>
<div class="team3"></div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.team1 {
  background: url("url of IMAGE1/a");
}

.team2 {
  background: url("url of IMAGE2/a");
}

.team3 {
  background: url("url of IMAGE3/a"); 
}

.team1:hover {
  background: url("url of IMAGE1/b");
}

.team2:hover {
  background: url("url of IMAGE2/b");
}

.team3:hover {
  background: url("url of IMAGE3/b");
}


.team1:hover ~ .team2 {
  /* this works */
  background: url("url of IMAGE 2/c");
}
/* this works */

.team1:hover ~ .team3 {
  /* this works */
  background: url("url of IMAGE 3/c");
}

.team2:hover ~ .team1 {
  /* this doesn’t work! */
  background: url("url of IMAGE 1/c"); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm scratching my head here. Bit confused by question. Can you try rephrasing?

Comment: @DavidWilkinson I think the OP wants all 3 backgrounds to change never mind what  image is hovered

Comment: Sorry :-) Seen the 3 div elements how can I select .team1 to behave some way when hovering .team2 ?

Comment: You'll need javascript for this. Are you using jquery?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered

Comment: Yes I am for this project

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `~` in CSS means that the element will come somewhere after the first element. In your case `team-3` cannot target `team-1` as it comes before `team-3`.

So `.team-3:hover ~ .team-1` won't work because 3 is after 1, but `.team-1:hover ~ .team-3` will work, because 1 is before 3.

So here is a jQuery solution to do what you want.

```js
$(".team-1").hover(
  function() {
    $(".team-1").addClass("team-1-1");
    $(".team-2").addClass("team-2-1");
    $(".team-3").addClass("team-3-1");
  },
  function() {
    $(".team-1").removeClass("team-1-1");
    $(".team-2").removeClass("team-2-1");
    $(".team-3").removeClass("team-3-1");
  }
);

$(".team-2").hover(
  function() {
    $(".team-1").addClass("team-1-2");
    $(".team-2").addClass("team-2-2");
    $(".team-3").addClass("team-3-2");
  },
  function() {
    $(".team-1").removeClass("team-1-2");
    $(".team-2").removeClass("team-2-2");
    $(".team-3").removeClass("team-3-2");
  }
);

$(".team-3").hover(
  function() {
    $(".team-1").addClass("team-1-3");
    $(".team-2").addClass("team-2-3");
    $(".team-3").addClass("team-3-3");
  },
  function() {
    $(".team-1").removeClass("team-1-3");
    $(".team-2").removeClass("team-2-3");
    $(".team-3").removeClass("team-3-3");
  }
);
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.team-1 { background: green; }
.team-2 { background: red; }
.team-3 { background: blue; }

.team-1-1 { background: chartreuse; }
.team-2-1 { background: deeppink; }
.team-3-1 { background: aqua; }

.team-1-2 { background: darkgreen; }
.team-2-2 { background: darkred; }
.team-3-2 { background: darkcyan; }

.team-1-3 { background: forestgreen; }
.team-2-3 { background: fuchsia; }
.team-3-3 { background: dodgerblue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-1"></div>
<div class="team-2"></div>
<div class="team-3"></div>
```

Comment: This won't change the other backgrounds when hovering over one element.

Comment: He wants "B" and "C" to change when you hover "A" (from what I can understand). Your code changes all three when you hover on container. Your snippet works, not sure if it's what he wants.

Comment: No but thanks. I actually need all 3 to change on hover, each having a different specified background

Comment: Yes, but you have it "change image A & B & C when hover container". Maybe that's what he wants. Not how I understood his question though.

Comment: @Wim fair enough - you can't target `team-1` from `team-3` because `team-3` comes after `team-1`. So you will have to use jQuery

Comment: @Wim np - glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

**This can not be done purely with css.** You must use JS instead.

You can do that in pur CSS **only if `.b` is after `.a` in the HTML**.

In below exemple :

- `.a:hover` => `.b` and `.c` work
- `.b:hover` => `.a` don't work because it's before ; `.c` work because it's after
- `.c:hover` => `.a` and `.b` don't work because there're before

```css
.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Manage A */
.a {
  background: green;
}
.a:hover ~ .b {
  background: #8AB800;
}
.a:hover ~ .c {
  background: #33FF66;
}
/* Manage B */
.b {
  background: red;
}
.b:hover ~ .a {
  background: #FF0080;
}
.b:hover ~ .c {
  background: #FF7A7A;
}
/* Manage C */
.c {
  background: blue;
}
.c:hover ~ .a {
  background: #7A7AFF;
}
.c:hover ~ .b {
  background: #00FFFF;
}
/* Manage all */
.a:hover, .b:hover, .c:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="a child"></div>
<div class="b child"></div>
<div class="c child"></div>
```

**An exemple in pur JS :**

```js
$('.child').css({
  'height': '100px',
  'width': '100px',
  'padding': '5px',
  'display': 'inline-block',
});
$('.a:hover,.b:hover,.c:hover').css('background', 'yellow');
$('.a').css('background', 'green').hover(function() {
  $('.b').css('background', '#8AB800');
  $('.c').css('background', '#33FF66');
});
$('.b').css('background', 'red').hover(function() {
  $('.a').css('background', '#FF0080');
  $('.c').css('background', '#FF7A7A');
});
$('.c').css('background', 'blue').hover(function() {
  $('.a').css('background', '#7A7AFF');
  $('.b').css('background', '#00FFFF');
});
```

```css
.a:hover, .b:hover, .c:hover {
background: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a child"></div>
<div class="b child"></div>
<div class="c child"></div>
```

Comment: This is not a answer. You say CSS wont work, use JS - where is the JS? Answers have to provide a solution - yours does not.

Comment: @CalvT : Maybe I'm not giving a turnkey solution ready-made but at least I explain why CSS solution can't work. (PS: I edit for add some JS exemple).

Comment: Yeah - well I explained in the comments, and if you look at revised edits, you will see that first I pursued a CSS solution as the OPs question wasn't clear, then he explained in more detail to me, so I created the jQuery solution. But fair comment, I've edited my answer to explain why it won't work.